# What is the encoding of this byte literal?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, protocol-buffers, bitcoin

I'm using the BTCRecover python scripts to try and dump the contents of an old (MultiBit Classic) bitcoin wallet. Specifically I'm trying to recover the private key. When I run the script it identifies the wallet as bitcoinj wallet format, which is apparently serialized using protocol buffers. The script fails with the error `"bitcoinj wallet is not encrypted"`. That's fine, I suspected it was not encrypted...I just want to dump the unencrypted keys.

I modified the Python script to print out the wallet after the protocol buffer has been deserialized, and this is the output (`secret_bytes` omitted):

```
Starting btcrecover 1.10.0-Cryptoguide on Python 3.9.5 64-bit, 21-bit unicodes, 64-bit ints
network_identifier: "org.bitcoin.production"
last_seen_block_hash: "\000\000\000\000\000\000\0019\017+j\246\336\317\251q\277zL;\302n\237\022\r.\032sM\240S\306"
key {
  type: ORIGINAL
  secret_bytes: "XXXXXXXX"
  public_key: "\003\nJK\303\3561\216\250\027\213\366X\374\262E)\010\022\215[%\224~\007K5\346*\372\315\231\222"
  creation_timestamp: 1365727360000
}
```

It appears that the file has been deserialized correctly, but the `last_seen_block_hash`, `public_key`, and `secret_bytes` don't make sense (to me, anyway). When I print just `public_key`, this is the result:

```
b'\x03\nJK\xc3\xee1\x8e\xa8\x17\x8b\xf6X\xfc\xb2E)\x08\x12\x8d[%\x94~\x07K5\xe6*\xfa\xcd\x99\x92'
```

I've tried running `.decode()` on the byte literal with many different encodings (utf-8, utf-16, utf-16-be, utf-32, latin1, ascii, etc.). In each case I either get an error or gibberish.

Does anyone know what encoding this is? Or is there a deeper issue here?

Comment: `In each case I either get an error or gibberish.` What exactly did you expect? Raw binary data isn't text.

Comment: @tkausl, right, I was hoping to convert the raw binary data to a string. Am I going about this incorrectly?

Comment: What encoding do you want? Hex? Base64? Choose one and encode.

Comment: When I run `>>> b'\x03\nJK\xc3\xee1\x8e\xa8\x17\x8b\xf6X\xfc\xb2E)\x08\x12\x8d[%\x94~\x07K5\xe6*\xfa\xcd\x99\x92'.encode("utf-8")`, I get:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

Answer (score -2):

The strings are using `latin1` encoding.

The `public_key` string contains a  33 byte compressed public key.
Converting it to a `P2PKH` address gives `19eBSVoQiDdJMuMAWToZB4qvGPii5s6Eie` which may look more familiar.

The `last_seen_block_hash` refers to block `00000000000001390f2b6aa6decfa971bf7a4c3bc26e9f120d2e1a734da053c6`, which is at height `230939` from 2013.